# build a shape class Triangle

Tags: c++, geometry, bounding-box

I have a very weird question for my assignment and I was wondering how to figure it out exactly.

The question asks:

- Create a base class Shape which will form the basis of your shapes. The Shape class will contain functions to calculate area and circumference of the shape, plus provide the coordinates (Points) of a rectangle that encloses the shape (a bounding box). These will be overloaded by the derived classes as necessary. Create a display() function that will display the name of the class plus all stored information about the class (including area, circumference, and bounding box).
- Build the hierarchy by creating the Shape classes Circle, Square, and Triangle. For these derived classes, create default constructors and constructors whose arguments can initialize the shapes appropriately using the correct number of Point objects (i.e., Circle requires a Point center and a radius; Square requires four Point vertices, while Triangle requires three Point vertices).
- In `main()`, create one instance each of the following: a Circle with a radius of 23, a Square with sides 25, and a Triangle with sides 10, 20, 30. Define all of them so that the origin (0,0) is somewhere within each object. Display the information from each object.

So I need to figure out the points that will create a triangle with sides 10, 20, 30.

Input:

```
Triangle t(Point(0,0), Point(0,20), Point(0,30));
```

Here is my code for Triangle:

```
class Triangle : public Shape
{
   Point s1, s2, s3;

public:
  Triangle() {}
  Triangle(const Point &p1, const Point &p2, const Point &p3) : s1(p1), s2(p2), s3(p3) {}

  void bbox()
  {  
     std::cout << "Triangle::bounding " << s1 << s2 << s3;
  }   

  void circumference() 
  {
     Point side1 = (s1 - s2);
     Point side2 = (s2 - s3);
     Point side3 = (s3 - s1);

     std::cout << "Triangle::perimeter " << side1.dist() + side2.dist() +   side3.dist();
  }

  void area() 
  {
     Point side1 = (s1 - s2);
     Point side2 = (s2 - s3);
     Point side3 = (s3 - s1);

     double half = (side1.dist() + side2.dist() + side3.dist())/2;    
     double answer = sqrt(half * (half - side1.dist()) * (half - side2.dist()) * (half - side3.dist()));

     std::cout << "Triangle::area " << answer;     
  }

};
```

This is the output:

```
Triangle::bounding (0,0)(0,20)(0,30)
Triangle::perimeter 60
Triangle::area 0
```

What is the best method to create a bounding box around the Triangle with sides 10,20,30 or any triangle for that matter.

Comment: you've mentioned _assignment_, and this looks like homework, so I've added the homework tag.

Comment: This seems more like a math question (leaving the programming part aside). Check out math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Start by drawing a picture. You might want to use a ruler or at least a straight edge. Can you draw a triangle that has sides with measurements 1 inch, 2 inches, and 3 inches? (Or use centimeters if that is more comfortable for you.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, I'm having difficulties understanding your question. Are you trying too identify which point is which? If you are trying to identify which point is which, draw a triangle on a grid paper with x/y axis. Label each side with A (leftmost), B(topmost) C(right most). Its then easy to figure out which side is which. E.g. A point will be the one with the  least x and y, B will be least y value and C will be most x. But it looks like u have all the info to draw an actual triangle, 3 vector points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no triangle with sides 10,20,30 with a non-zero area, so what you state is correct:

> Triangle::bounding (0,0)(0,20)(0,30)
>   Triangle::perimeter 60
>   Triangle::area 0

But what you call bounding in that list is the corners of the triangle, not the bounding box.

If this shape should actually be called a triangle is a matter of definition, but since that's built in to the question I would not think too much about that. Either your teacher is trying to make you confused or he/she did not think it through.

The bounding box 'around (well, touching) any polygon is the rectangle with corners at

```
(xmin,ymin)-(xmin,ymax)-(xmax,ymax)-(xmax,ymin)
```

so, in your case

```
(0,0) - (0,30) - (0,30) - (0,0)
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is trying to create a bounding box around it. There should be four points and because they gave me 10,20,30 it really confuses me. lol :(

Comment: The bottom left corner of your bounding box is `(min(x1,x2,x3), min(y1,y2,y3)`.  The top-right corner of your box is `(max(x1,x2,x3), max(y1,y2,y3)`.  This is not C++ code, by the way - you can translate. =)

Comment: I'm working on some min() and max() functions to figure this out. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

They asked for the **sides** to be of length 10, 20, 30...  They did not say that your points should be at (0,10), (0,20), (0,30) - those points are all on a line, which is why your area is zero.  You need basic trigonometry here.

Look at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolvingObliqueTriangles/

The law of cosines will help you.  If you have three edge `a, b, c` define your first edge `a` as (0,0) to (10,0).  That's two points already.  The third point is found by solving:  `b^2 = a^2 + c^2 -2*a*c*cos(B)` where B is the angle between edges `a` and `c`.  *ie* the angle at the origin.  So let's say you want edge `c` to be 30 units long (and so `b` is 20)...

```
double a=10, b=20, c=30;
double B = acos((a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2*a*c));
```

Now you know the angle `B` and length `c` you can use trig to work out `(x,y)`: the position of your third point.  Since you're starting at the origin this is the easiest form.  Maybe you can do that part on your own.

Comment: Incidentally, having a class with void functions for calculating values is not very useful.  Make them return a value instead, and do the `cout` from whoever asks for the value.  *ie* `std::cout << "Triangle::area " << t.area() << std::endl;`

Comment: Hi Paddy, when I do what you say the angle is 180 degrees. Did I do that wrong? Also my void functions are virtual functions I just didn't add that part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for alignment issues but if anyone was interested in the finished code here it is.

The void functions are "virtual"

```
  virtual void area() = 0;
  virtual void circumference() = 0;
  virtual void bbox() = 0;
  virtual void display();
```

All my classes display inside display(). I'm curious though if anyone has any idea's to compress the code further, I'm new to C++ so everything might seem expanded out.

```
class Triangle : public Shape
{
   Point s1, s2, s3;

   public:
   Triangle() {}
   Triangle(const Point &p1, const Point &p2, const Point &p3) : s1(p1), s2(p2), s3(p3) {}

void bbox()
{   
  Point b1 = min(s1, s2, s3); 
  Point b3 = max(s1, s2, s3);
  Point b2 = min_max(s1, s2, s3);
  Point b4 = max_min(s1, s2, s3);

  std::cout << "Triangle::bounding " << b1 << b2 << b3 << b4;
}     

void circumference() 
{
  Point side1 = (s1 - s2);
  Point side2 = (s2 - s3);
  Point side3 = (s3 - s1);

  std::cout << "Triangle::perimeter " << side1.dist() + side2.dist() + side3.dist();
}

   void area() 
   {
     Point side1 = (s1 - s2);
     Point side2 = (s2 - s3);
     Point side3 = (s3 - s1);

     double half = (side1.dist() + side2.dist() + side3.dist())/2;    
     double answer = sqrt(half * (half - side1.dist()) * (half - side2.dist()) * (half - side3.dist()));

     std::cout << "Triangle::area " << answer;     
   } 
};
```

Let me know what you think.

Thanks.